# How to configure SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, database, vb.net, sql-server-express, sql-server-2005-express

I have just downloaded SQL Server 2005 express edition from here:

To be used as a database for a vb.net program.

But I'm confused in using sql server. I do not know where to start from here:

http://screencast.com/t/ZTdiMDU5

Do I have to create the database in vb.net?-->

http://screencast.com/t/ZjRlYjkx

If not, where could I create the ms sql database? I'm a beginner and I want to learn.

Please help.

Do you have any tutorials there that could help a beginner like me.

Comment: SQL Server configuration questions need to be addressed to ServerFault.com, not to SO.  Once the Server is properly installed and configured, _programming_ questions (such as running queries, including Database CREATEing queries, from say VB or some other language, or even plain SQL language questions) are welcomed here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [SQL Server 2005 Express for Beginners](http://www.asp.net/learn/sql-videos/)